# Adding dimensions 'loses' data compared to less dimensions

Tags: google-analytics-4

Querying the Google Data Api, and also using the GA4 explorer..

```
https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/query-explorer/
```

Querying using a single day as the date, with the Dimension of googleAdsCampaignName and metrics of advertiserAdcost.

This returns 6 rows as shown:

[image]

Ive checked these numbers with Adwords and they match, totaling 541.68

Now, if I add googleAdsAdGroupName, I get more rows of course (43 of them), but they only add up to 427.21

[image]

Theres no 'Other' row, and trying to understand what is happening is proving difficult. It seems the only way of getting the full amount is to only have 1 dimension, so I tried with just the googleAdsAdGroupName, and still get 43 rows, totaling 427.21 - a loss of 114.47

Not only are the numebrs wrong but whole Ad Groups are missing. e.g. the Cdw group is missing when more than the campaiginname is added to the dimensions, but is clearly there in the explore tools.

[image]

Suggestions? Thanks.